# Download of ADT Plugin for Android

Tags: android

During the installation of ADT Plugin for Android, I am stuck. During its downloading, it gives an error message. I click on OK and then nothing happens after that. What to do now?

Comment: "it gives an error message." You didn't think giving details in regards to that error message might be worthwhile?

Answer (score 1):

First, remove entries for ADT; then update your Eclipse installation. Install it again according to [these instructions](http://krishanzone.blogspot.com/2012/09/getting-started-with-android.html).